# How do I make a modal open only the first time a user visits the page?

Tags: modal-dialog, session-storage

I am using Bootstrap 5.0.2 as the basis of my website, I finally got the modal to appear on page opening, thanks stack overflow, my aim is to not have the modal appear should the visitor move to another page and then return.
This is the code for running the modal. What do I need to add to make it only function the first time this page is viewed per session?

```
<script>
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
const modal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.querySelector('#myModal'));
modal.show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to implement [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage).

When a user visits the page, we check to see if the sessionStorage contains a value for the modal. If it is the first time they load the page, it would not contain a value as we haven't set anything to it yet. In that case, we show the modal as normal and set a value for the sessionStorage. That way, when the user refreshes the page the value is already set in sessionStorage so the if statement will not run.

```
 window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

          if (!sessionStorage.getItem("modal")) {
            const modal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.querySelector('#myModal'));
            modal.show();
            sessionStorage.setItem("modal", "blah");
          }

        });
```

Comment: Ok, thanks very much. I think I'm beginning to get it now. What is "blah" though?

Comment: @RedDog its just a random value I've assigned to the `modal` key. You can change it to whatever. Doesn't matter what the value is because we aren't using it in any way, we just care about whether or not the modal key has a value, not what the value actually is.

Comment: I have now added a modal to a second page, how do I get the two modals to act independently? The first modal opens on the index page, I then close it, but when I go to the next page with a modal, it doesn't appear because I have session storage set. The modals have different IDs. How do I create a seperate session storage ID?

Comment: I belive I have figured it out. I changed the 'get item' and 'set item' to modal2, and the  ID to myModal2 along with .querySelector to myModal2. It appears to be working!